# Excel: Is there a formula to reference a row of pivot table?

Tags: pivot, excel-2010, pivot-table, powerpivot

I've been working with Excel for many years and I have never come up with a solution to this problem. I have a pivot table which is performing all of my basic summaries. The data is divided into "Items" along the row fields and "Weeks" along the columns with a sum of my "Quantity" in the Values field. What I want is to be able to reference a row of this data and use it in a sumproduct formula. Think of it as using GETPIVOTDATA to return a row instead of one value. It would use it this way:

`=SUMPRODUCT('PivotRow','PivotRow' > 10)`

What this formula would do is exclude all of the PivotFields where the value was below 10. What I don't know how to do is reference a row of a PivotTable. Is there some super special way to use GETPIVOTDATA that I am not aware of? I love PivotTables to build summaries of data but I typically need to build an analysis on top of that summary which can be very frustrating. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am working with PowerPivot so I have that functionality available to me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential approach to this problem is to use cube sets or named sets to extract out that specific value form the cube source instead of actually querying the actual PivotTable instead.

For more information, check out: http://dennyglee.com/2010/02/04/pivots-cube-formulas-named-sets-oh-my/.